# get decimals from contract

Tags: web3js, erc-20

What is the correct way to get the number of decimals using web3? For example, how would I get the number 6 as a result when trying to obtain USDT decimals from the contract address?

I was using contract.methods.decimals().call() but it returns this

RETURN VALUE I GET  { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] }

```
async getTokenInfo(tx) {
try {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, tx.to);
  const symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call();
  const decimals = await contract.methods.decimals().call;

  return { symbol: symbol, decimals: decimals };
} catch (error) {
  console.log("getTokenInfo", error);
}
```

Comment: It should actually works. From where come „contract“ can you show how u assign the value to the contract variable

Comment: And have u used await before that ....call()

Comment: Im using await with it. I use the abi from the package human-standard-token-abi and the message I obtain the decimals (or want to is this). The symbols are working correctly, decimals not.


  async getTokenInfo(tx) {
    try {
      const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, tx.to);
      const symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call();
      const decimals = await contract.methods.decimals().call;

      return { symbol: symbol, decimals: decimals };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("getTokenInfo", error);
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

nevermind guys, I forgot the "()" after the call...